# CSS: Is there any way to select an item to be hidden besides tag, class, or ID?

Tags: css, html

Here's my situation: I have a web-based app (Jira) that I'm using that I'd like to modify slightly by using my own code via the [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) Chrome extension. In one column of the app, there are symbols showing "low priority" and "high priority" arrows. I want to hide all of the low priority symbols.

Normally it'd be easy. I'd just use something like this:

```
.prioritysymbol.low img {display: none}
```

However, the code isn't marked up to allow me to target specific images like that.

Are there any other ways for me to target those images? It'd be nice if I could target by SRC, ALT, or TITLE, since those are all different based on the version of the image.

Thanks!

Comment: This shows absolutely no research or effort given. It is a duplicate of several posts on StackExchange. Please put for more effort before posting next time!

Comment: Thanks for that. I did actually do research to try to find the answer before I resorted to asking it here. Some things are just ungoogleable. Please put less condescension into your comment next time!

Comment: Sorry for coming across that way, but it is frustrating when you can [search](https://goo.gl/39GDkp) [your](https://goo.gl/CVtEFE) [question](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+select+element+by+TITLE&rlz=1C1ASUT_en-GBAU463AU463&oq=css+select+element+by+TITLE&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5216j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and get the answer in the very first or first few links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attributes as selectors in CSS.

`[attr]` Selects an element with an attribute name of attr.

`[attr=value]` Selects an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".

`[attr~=value]` Selects an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "value".

`[attr|=value]` Selects an element with an attribute name of attr. Its value can be exactly “value” or can begin with “value” immediately followed by “-” (U+002D). It can be used for language subcode matches.

`[attr^=value]` Selects an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".

`[attr$=value]` Selects an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is suffixed by "value".

`[attr*=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

---

This, for example, will target all internal links (`href` attribute beginning with `#`):

```
a[href^="#"] { background-color: #000; }
```

---

You can read more about attribute selectors here:

- [CSS-Tricks - Attribute Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)
- [CSS 2.1 Specification - Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)
- [CSS Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)